# http request throws an exception on calling destroy

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I have a node js project which makes multiple http connections with the server to download a file. In case no data in received from any of those connections for a particular duration of time then I forcefully throw a **time out exception** and close the open connection by calling destroy.

As soon as I call the `response.destroy()` method the exception that I receive is as follows - 
[image: Here]

I am not able to figure out from the stack trace what is the cause of this error and how should be handling it. Please help

Comment: Are you sure that your are connected to your server ?

Comment: I am not really sure when I look at the code it seems like I have not handled closed connections properly. It is possible that I face this issue because I was calling the ```destroy``` method for already closed connections.

Comment: I confirmed, you were right. Thanks!